# Uniform convergence of the sequence of derivative functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I am self-learning Real Analysis from the text *Understanding Analysis* by Stephen Abbott. I would like for someone to verify if my proof is technically correct and sufficiently rigorous.

**Theorem 6.3.2** Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of differentiable functions defined on the closed interval $[a,b]$ and assume that $(f_n')$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$. If there exists a point $x_0 \in [a,b]$ where $f_n(x_0)$ is convergent, then $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$.

> **[Abbott 6.3.7]** Use the Mean Value Theorem to supply a proof for theorem 6.3.2. To get started observe that the triangle inequality implies that, for any $x \in [a,b]$ and $m,n \in\mathbf{N}$,

\begin{align*}
|f_n(x) - f_m(x)| \leq |(f_n(x) - f_m(x))-(f_n(x_0) - f_m(x_0))| + |f_n(x_0) - f_m(x_0)| 
\end{align*}

***Proof.***

Pick an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$.

Fix $x \in [a,b]$ and consider the closed interval $[x,x_0]$ ($[x_0,x]$ if $x_0 < x$).

Since $f_n - f_m$ is continuous on $[x_0,x]$ and differentiable on $(x_0,x)$, by the Mean Value Theorem(MVT), there exists $\alpha \in (x,x_0)$, such that:

\begin{align*}
|(f_n(x)-f_m(x))-(f_n(x_0)-f_m(x_0))| &=|f_n'(\alpha) - f_m'(\alpha)|\cdot|x - x_0|\\
&\leq |f_n'(\alpha) - f_m'(\alpha)|\cdot|b-a|
\end{align*}

Since $(f_n')$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$, there exists $N_1 \in \mathbf{N}$ such that for all $n > m \geq N_1$ and for all $x \in [a,b]$,

\begin{align*}
|f_n'(x) - f_m'(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2 |b-a|}
\end{align*}

Since $(f_n(x_0))$ is convergent, by the Cauchy criterion for sequences of real numbers, there exists $N_2(x_0,\epsilon)$, such that for all $n > m \geq N_2$,

\begin{align*}
|f_n(x_0) - f_m(x_0)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}
\end{align*}

If we pick $N = \max\{N_1,N_2\}$, then for all $n > m \geq N$ and for all $x \in [a,b]$,

\begin{align*}
|f_n(x) - f_m(x)| < \epsilon
\end{align*}

Note that, neither $N_1$ nor $N_2$ are functions of $x$, so our choice of $N$ works regardless of what $x$ is. This closes the proof.

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Comment: The last sentence is good, because it clarifies that you really are proving uniformity. However, even though you included the last sentence, I would still suggest reorganizing the proof so that you first introduce $N_1,N_2$, and then you fix $x\in [a,b]$ (just so your arguemnt reads more clearly in order : $\epsilon$ first, then $N_1,N_2$ and then $N=\max(N_1,N_2)$, and then for all $x$...)